# Either $a^{2}\neq b^{2}$ or $a^3\neq b^3.$

Tags: group-theory

If a and b are distinct group elements, prove that either $a^{2}\neq b^{2}$ or $a^3\neq b^3.$

I tried doing the operation by inverses to get the identity, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a^{3}=b^{3}$ and $a^{2}=b^{2}$. Then $a^{-2}=b^{-2}$. Thus $a^{3}a^{-2}=b^{3}b^{-2}\Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Assume that both $a^2=b^2$ and $a^3=b^3$.  Using this, can you show that $a=b$?

If so, then for distinct elements $a$ and $b$, it is impossible to satisfy both equalities.

Comment: Self-inverting elements can satisfy a^2=b^2 and be distinct.  How does make a^3=/=b^3 generally?

Comment: @newyorkwedge the point is that you can show that two elements satisfying both equalities must be identical - so that distinct elements cannot satisfy both. Then given distinct elements, at least one of the two equalities must be false.

Comment: @newyorkwedge If you want to consider the special case of self-inverting elements, note that $a^3=a(a^2)=a$ and $b^3=b(b^2)=b$. So, even though $a^2=b^2=1$, $a^3\neq b^3$.

Answer (score 1):

I will proceed by contradiction by first assuming that $a\neq b$, $a^2=b^2$, and $a^3=b^3$.
Consider $a^2=b^2$. Acting on the left by $a^{-2}$ yields $e=a^{-2}b^2$. Acting on the right by $b^{-2}$ implies $b^{-2}=a^{-2}$. We can use this fact to complete our proof. Consider $a^3=b^3$. Acting on the left by $b^{-2}=a^{-2}$ gives $a=b$. This contradicts the supposition. Q.E.D

Comment: I guess the downvote is because people find it distracting when people dredge up old questions with good answers. (On the other hand, I find it unhelpful when people downvote reasonable answers by new users and don't comment.)

Comment: I agree. It contributes to the pool of knowledge freely available to everyone on the internet. This question is from a textbook, and this page will likely be viewed by others in the future.